# Set offline failed for database 'MyDB'

Tags: sql-server, database

My program failed by this exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
The transaction log for database 'MyDB' is full. 
To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases
```

I noticed that my tables doesn't load in SQL Management Studio and i cann't open database properties window

[image: The Error when I try open Property window]

Then I try to change my log file to autogrowth by this statement:

```
 ALTER DATABASE MyDB
 MODIFY FILE
 (NAME=MyDB_Log,MAXSIZE=2TB,FILEGROWTH=20MB);
```

this statement executed successfully but doesn't help me to recover my database
Then i try to set offline MyDB the operation failed by some exception 
Then i set the database in single user mode but the exception still exists
Then i try this statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET EMERGENCY;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set single_user
GO
DBCC CHECKDB (MyDB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set multi_user
GO
```

This statement failed too on first line.

And now i don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps.

- Open up SQL Management Studio and connect to your database server
- Right-click your database
- Click Properties
- Click the Options link
- Set the Recovery Model to Simple as follows

[image]

- Click OK
- Once this is complete, right click on the database again
- Click Tasks>Shrink>Files
- On the Shrink Database window select the file type as 'Log' .  The file name appears in     the filename drop down as databasename_log as follows:

[image]

The space used versus the space allocated displays. After you set the recovery model to Simple, the majority of the space in the transaction log released.

- Ensure that the Release unused space radio button is selected.
- Click OK on this window to shrink the transaction log.

You might also want to read through this short post
http://sqlity.net/en/556/t-sql-tuesday-25-%E2%80%93-sql-server-tips-tricks/

Comment: Setting to "Simple" breaks the backup chain (if one exists). A transaction log backup should do the trick if there isn't one ancient transaction blocking the space release. In that case that transaction needs to be aborted before doing the log backup.

Comment: i can't open database properties window